# webpack is not working properly in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

i have created an "hello-world" react app using `create-react-app` command, then i tried to run the same files using `webpack`, but it does not working properly, like `.ico`, `.css` files are `not rendering` to the screen.. please help me to solve this issue.

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'style-loader'
        },
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            modules: true,
            // camelCase: true,
            sourceMap: true
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      test: /\.svg$/,
      loaders: [
        'babel-loader',
        {
          loader: 'react-svg-loader',
          query: {
            jsx: true
          }
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      test: /\.json$/,
      loader: 'json-loader',
    },
    {
      test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico)$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader:'file-loader?name=img/[path][name].[ext]&context=./app/images'
   }
  ]
  },
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
  }
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "indecision-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "Andrew Mead",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "live-server public/",
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "live-server": "^1.2.0",
    "react": "15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "15.6.1",
    "react-svg-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
    "validator": "8.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.5.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "webpack": "^2.7.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.14",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.5.1"
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["env", "react"]
}
```

Remaining file are same as `auto-generated` while creating create-react-app. help me to solve this issue

Comment: Did you eject your CRA?

Comment: @ChrisR No, how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `create-react-app` already has his webpack configuration, babel configuration and everything else inside it's own `node_module`s.

I can see that you changed the start and build commands. The default commands that `create-react-app` sets here already runs the scripts that calls webpack (with babel and etc), with the correct configuration (that handles the `.ico` files and everything else)

If you want to deal with it on your own you can eject your `create-react-app`. This means to throw all config files and scripts on the root of your project and remove the modules that `create-react-app` installed for you. You can learn more about it [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#whats-included) and about the command that ejects the project for you [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-eject)

If you want to change webpack configurations without ejecting, you can use [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired). (as I want to keep updates coming from the create-react-app repo, I'm using this alternative)

Answer (score 1):

1. Git commit the all changes
2. Run this command on cmd :> npm run eject
3. Go generated folder name: config>webpack.config.dev.js>line#166 (approximate) CSS compiler
   Append the code on options object

   `importLoaders: 1,`
   `modules: true,`
   `localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]',`
4. And also add config>webpack.config.prod.js> line#183 (approximate) css compiler
   Append the above code on options object

   `importLoaders: 1,`
   `modules: true,`
   `localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]',`
5. Then restart the server.
6. Now adding class like that.

   `import classes from './App.css';`
   `<div className={classes.App}>`

Comment: Please explain the reasons behind your steps.

Comment: The reason is `base64:5` conversion