# How to import scss file as variable in react with typescript

Tags: reactjs

I am unable to import scss file in below format.

```
import * as styles from './index.scss';
```

getting below `error` :

> can not find module './index.scss'

I want to use class name like below :

```
className={styles.anyClassName}
```

Comment: Take a look here: https://javascriptplayground.com/css-modules-webpack-react/

Answer (score 33):

In order to import SCSS as object in TS like this :

```
import * as styles from './index.scss';
```

- Create file 'global.d.ts' in your source directory (or outside, but must be included in the src directory defined in tsconfig)
- Add the following code inside

```
declare module '*.scss' {
  const content: {[className: string]: string};
  export = content;
}
```

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/ambient/d.ts.html

Answer (score 3):

I came across this question recently, and figured it might be useful to add an answer that helps do this at the time the project is generated (using create-react-app) and without the need to eject or modify the webpack configs:

`create-react-app my-app --scripts-version=react-scripts-scss-ts`

Answer (score 2):

Be sure you have `react-scripts-scss-ts` installed.

If not run:

```
 npm i react-scripts-scss-ts --save
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved that issue using Run Powershell as Administrator and execute that code:
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
Press A And Enter

Refer this if not clear:  [After npm updating packages .ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57673913/vsc-powershell-after-npm-updating-packages-ps1-cannot-be-loaded-because-runnin)

and refer this alsp:
[No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45251645/error-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-scandir)

Answer (score -1):

One of this way you work with `.scss` style on your `create-react-app` project. you need some steps on your projects.

1. git commit all changes
2. run `yarn run eject` from your project command prompt.
3. Go to the location and open the file `config/webpack.config.dev.js` approximately line #173. Replace `test: /\.css$/,` with `test: /\.s?css$/,`
4. Go to the location and open the file `config/webpack.config.prod.js` approximately line #185. Replace `test: /\.css$/,` with `test: /\.s?css$/,`
5. add your `.scss` file on your component like

   ```
   import './App.scss';
   ```

   and uses like

   ```
   <div className="your-styled-class-name">
       <p>Styed Text</p>
   </div>
   ```

That's it.

Comment: Hi, I want to import as import * as styles from 'xyz.css'. That is not working.

Comment: if using `create-react-app` command then follow this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49856468/webpack-is-not-working-properly-in-react-js/49856807#49856807

Comment: Yes i am using create-react-project with typescript. The above approach also not works. Please check git repo: https://github.com/mdarif-k/React-Typescript1.git

Comment: hi. I have updated my answer. this time you create a fresh project then try this way. I have checked it.

Comment: import './style.scss' works, import * as styles from './style.scss' doesn't. Is it possible to use scss as we would do with css ?

Comment: Ejecting the app seems like it should be a solution of last resort, as it introduces a bunch of configuration and infrastructure that's probably best left under the hood into your codebase. Flexibility can be nice, but clarity is often nicer, and configuring webpack can turn into a pretty deep rabbit hole. Just my two cents.