# VSC PowerShell. After npm updating packages .ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system

Tags: firebase, powershell, vue.js, npm, visual-studio-code

I design websites in VSC and PowerShell is my default terminal.

After updating and deploying a website to firebase earlier, I was prompted to update firebase tools - which I did using npm. Immediately after I cannot run/access any firebase scripts wthout the folllowing error:

`firebase : File C:\Users\mada7\AppData\Roaming\npm\firebase.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. At line:1 char:1`

`firebase
  + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess`

I've spent a few hours searching around and can't find a solid answer the problem. Many threads are several years old and I find it bizarre I've not had this problem in the past year until today.
I can still access firebase scripts if I set my default terminal to cmd.

Assuming the problem was related to firebase-tools I've carried on working but have now updated vue.js and get the error again when trying to run any vue commands in powershell:

`vue : File C:\Users\mada7\AppData\Roaming\npm\vue.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. At line:1 char:1`

`vue
  + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess`

`VSCode Version:
Version: 1.37.1 (user setup)
Commit: f06011a
Date: 2019-08-15T16:17:55.855Z
Electron: 4.2.7
Chrome: 69.0.3497.128
Node.js: 10.11.0
V8: 6.9.427.31-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.18362
OS Version:
Windows 10 Home
Version - 1903
OS build - 18362.295`

I've been reading around and seen many threads around permissions for scripts, but I haven't changed any - indeed the PowerShell scripts worked right up until I updated my packages. No other settings touched in the mean time. I don't want to be changing PowerShell settings unnecessarily.

Comment: This problem started for several application using npm around November of 2019. It's then that npm started using powershell scripts.  See [this](https://github.com/npm/read-cmd-shim/pull/6) npm pull request and this subsequent npm issue 470.  https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/470

Answer (score 267):

This is a powershell security policy, to fix it, run Powershell as administrator and run the following

```
PS C:\> Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

If you don't want to run the command as an administrator but just for the current user, you can add a scope like below

```
PS C:\> Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

The stricter the policy, the more secure your system becomes.

You can change RemoteSigned to other options like: `Restricted`, `AllSigned`, `RemoteSigned`, `Unrestricted`

Source: https://tecadmin.net/powershell-running-scripts-is-disabled-system/

Alternatively you can modify `C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\powershell.config.json` using a text editor and add or modify the following section.

```
{
   ....

   "Microsoft.PowerShell:ExecutionPolicy":  "RemoteSigned"
}
```

You can also run your script without modifying security policies by using the `command prompt` as noted by [ztom's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69987387/4393351).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I had actually already come across that website and am reluctant to change anything as the error came about without me changing anything or installing/restarting the computer.
I have now changed my settings in PowerShell and it runs scripts as before, is there anything I should be concerned with having changed this?
I originally posted the question on gitHub and a couple of people have the same issue.
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1627

Comment: @Aponting As long as you don’t have malicious software on your pc that may route data to an external server, it should be fine. Better to also have an antivirus installed but I don’t think it’s too much to worry about if you don’t use dodgy websites or software

Comment: Executing `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` in the windows powershell works now. Thank you.

Comment: Thx. Worked for me too. But Microsoft why?! Coming from a Linux system its quite irritating.

Answer (score 236):

Just delete `firebase.ps1` file:

File `C:\Users\<your account>\AppData\Roaming\npm\firebase.ps1`

Comment: i dont have firebase.ps1 in \AppData\Roaming\npm folder

Comment: helped to me as well... in my case it was vue.ps1, just removed it and all worked well...

Comment: in my case it was touch.ps1, moved it from there and it works now! nO iDeA if what i did is right or wrong

Comment: I was facing the same issue with http-server.ps1 deleting the file resolved the problem

Comment: 100% works for me. It may be either firebase.ps1 or vue.ps1, just delete it.

Comment: Worked as well, in my case it was the file yarn.ps1

Comment: Worked for me, I had the same issue but with Vue.

Comment: Why does it work after deleting the .ps1 and why .ps1 file causing this issue?

Comment: The files mentioned in the answer were not present for me. When i did a npm --version, I got an error stating C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.ps1 cannot be loaded .Similarly for npx also. Once I removed these 2 files from the above path, the error was gone. Not sure why this happened, but if someone could explain on the reason for this, that would be super helpful.

Comment: Perfect answer. For my case it was vue.ps1 I deleted this and it worked. Thanks

Comment: FINNALY!! I spent hours trying to solve it!! But why this file is causing the problem?

Comment: Worked for me as well for yarn.ps1. Anyway can someone explain how this work?

Answer (score 36):

A little clarification: when you run PowerShell as Admin, in most cases you don't need to note a path. Just type:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

then press "A", then "Enter"

Comment: This is just worked man.. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 19):

For those who work with VS Code and get the `about_Execution_Policies` error. In my case with the command `ncu -u` ([npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates)).

Try it with CMD:

[image]

Simply execute the command in CMD again.

If this works, the security settings can remain as they are.

Comment: This solve my issue.

Comment: Yes this works for me too

Comment: IDEA has the same option

Comment: This is the best answer, as we don't have to touch the security settings as well.

Answer (score 16):

Also, one thing worth mentioning is that you need to open PowerShell as Admin and then change the policy like so.

PS C:\> Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

[Reference - Using the Set-ExecutionPolicy Cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-powershell-1.0/ee176961(v=technet.10))

Answer (score 14):

I didn't have any problem with npm but the same problem is in the using yarn on windows.
In my case, I **deleted** yarn.ps1 and it worked fine for me:

File path:

```
C:\Users\<your account>\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.ps1
```

Answer (score 12):

1. search for *powershell*.
2. *right click* and **run as administration**.
3. run this simple command `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`.
4. Press **A** And **Enter**.
5. go to code and run **yarn add <YOUR_MODULE>**.
6. press Enter.

congratulations now it would be done.

Answer (score 9):

This could be due to the current user having an undefined ExecutionPolicy.

You could try the following

`Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`

Answer (score 5):

I also had this problem in the powershell and i used the following :
 then i again installed the serve package.

```
 Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser
```

and then i chose `Unrestricted` and gave `serve` command and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

File `C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\vue.ps1` cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.

I had the same error message with vue.
After running the below command successfully

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
```

when i ran commands like `vue` or `vue --version`, i received that error message.

This is how i fixed it:
I pressed the buttons `windows + E`, clicked `view`, checked `hidden items`.
Then, i went to `C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm` folder and deleted the vue file of type `'windows powershell script'`.
After that, i ran the commands `vue` and `vue --version` succesfully.
Hope this helps.

Comment: As an update - I regularly get the error after updating firebase & vue and so delete the relevant .ps file each time without issues as I'm reluctant to alter script settings

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `PowerShell` and changing its security settings, you can simply use `cmd` instead. It will not give an error and your all commands will run smoothly.

> Remember PowerShell is stronger and sensitive. So, Microsoft by default disables running .ps1 files as it can cause a security issue and harm your pc. So, that's why you should try to use cmd instead of changing PowerShell security.

Answer (score 4):

Open Powershell from your VS code  and then execute this command on that:

```
set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

this worked for me. it will ask you for CLI authentication.

Comment: Apply 1 for value after command is exceuted

Answer (score 4):

Open powershell on  run as administrator.

run this command
`Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` as shown:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

Execution Policy Change
The execution policy helps protect you from scripts that you do not trust. Changing the execution policy might expose
you to the security risks described in the about_Execution_Policies help topic at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. Do you want to change the execution policy?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "N"): A
```

press Enter.

This fix my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Open Powershell and execute this command:

```
set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

Answer (score 3):

Delete `firebase.ps1` located in:

```
C:\Users\<your account>\AppData\Roaming\npm\
```

In case you don't have `firebase.ps1` delete `vue.ps1`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you have this issue in VS Code, close PowerShell terminal and open a Command Prompt terminal instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
PS C:\> Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

It's works for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it can help with Firebase but I had a similar problem installing Vue with `*>npm install -g @vue/cli*` .

Long story short:
I deleted ***vue.ps1*** from `C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\` and installed it locally (without `-g`) from powershell terminal inside VsCode `*>npm install @vue/cli*`.
After that I could use Vue commands without problems.

Answer (score 1):

**Close all instances of cmd, PowerShell, and VS Code.**

**Right-click on VS Code and choose Run as Administrator.**

**In the VS Code terminal, run the following command:**

```
  Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

now To check, click this command on terminal    `firebase --version`

Answer (score 0):

Just delete **Power Shell** file:

`C:\Users\<your account>\AppData\Roaming\npm\**vue**`

Delete this last vue file, extension of this file is power shall

after delete run command it's work.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same problem when i got android studio flamingo update , while working with firebase cli i got the error shown below,
[image]

that moment i went to the same project directory in my file explorer and opened cmd at the location,

Surprisingly, things worked as normal,
[image: My command on normal cmd at same location]
I then thought that it might be an issue with terminal of my android studio.
I checked that my terminal was set to power shell and that was the real cause of the problem .

[image: Change Power-shell to command prompt]

so i toggled the terminal as command prompt ,and things again started working as normal.

[image: Same code started working without any error]

Answer (score 0):

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Then

Press - A
I hope it will work for you !
[image]

Answer (score -1):

On a computer with German as the default language the error might look like:

```
vue : Die Datei "C:\Program Files\nodejs\vue.ps1" kann nicht geladen werden, da die Ausführung von Skripts auf diesem System deaktiviert ist. Weitere Informationen finden Sie unter "about_Execution_Policies"         
(https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170).
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ vue --version
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : Sicherheitsfehler: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

I had to search for `"vue" "PSSecurityException"` to find this thread.

I installed a new node version with nvm-windows. Then I installed vue-cli. After that a simple `vue --version` led to the error above.

It seems like the removal of the `vue.ps1` file helped to resolve my problem like some users suggested above.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue during installation of grunt and yarn.

"yarn : File C:*\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file C:*\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.ps1 is not digitally signed. You cannot run this script on the current system. For more information about running scripts and
setting execution policy, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170."

When I checked the AppData\Roaming\npm* folder, I could see grunt script being generated as:

- Windows Command Script
- Windows Powershell Script

Upon deletion of the powershell script, the error was gone.

Answer (score -1):

**Just open cmd as administrator and go to your project**

`then execute your firebase command`

Comment: You're saying to use `cmd.exe` instead of PowerShell?  That has already been suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71098500/150605) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67639276/150605), while the question itself acknowledges that possibility with "I can still access firebase scripts if I set my default terminal to cmd."  Of course, that doesn't actually fix the problem.

Comment: @LanceU.Matthews Thanks for your comment. You mentioned two answers and the question acknowledgment where they said about default cmd, not as admin. For this, I added an answer. And I also found this exact error and solved it by cmd admin.