# unable to run command "vue create app1"

Tags: vue.js, npm, vue-cli, vue-cli-4

when i try to run any command at cli it gives this error:

> vue : File C:\Users\john\AppData\Roaming\npm\vue.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see
> about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
> At line:1 char:1
>
> - vue create app1
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
>   ```

any solution to solve it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSC PowerShell. After npm updating packages .ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57673913/vsc-powershell-after-npm-updating-packages-ps1-cannot-be-loaded-because-runnin)

Comment: @greenjaed  no..

Comment: @johndoe Did you try the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57675039/6277151) that sets the permission policy, and then rerun your command in that terminal? If so, what was the result?

Answer (score 0):

If you only tried to run it with PowerShell, switch to CMD and run the command.