# I'm facing problem with install yarn and use it but node is working finely

Tags: javascript, reactjs

yarn : File C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this
system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- yarn
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
  ```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSC PowerShell. After npm updating packages .ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57673913/vsc-powershell-after-npm-updating-packages-ps1-cannot-be-loaded-because-runnin)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

Npm worked fine for me, but yarn also had some Windows problems. According to my experience, deleting yarn.ps1 solved the problem:

C:\Users{YourUserName}\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.ps1

Answer (score 3):

If you are using vscode interpreter then change your interpreter to command prompt from powershell and try. My problem solved by changing it
[image]